# Отрицательные индексы элементов массива C++

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Возможно начать индексацию массива с -50 и закончить 50 ?
Как обозначить, что индексировать массив надо с -50? 
Тут в таком случае, какое kk задавать ?

```
double *bx = new double [kk];
```

Comment: `double *bx_save = new double [101]; double *bx = bx_save+50;` :)

Comment: @Harry А как перебрать такой массив с -50 по 50 . for(kk=-50;kk<=50;kk++) {}

Comment: Так и перебрать - `for(int kk=-50;kk<=50;kk++) { printf("%d\n",bx[kk]); }` Удалять только потом надо `bx_save`. И еще - поменть тэг, потому что в С нет никакого `new`...

Comment: @Harry Мне надо на C++/ Я не знаю почему не меняется С на С++

Comment: Да что вы так старательно убираете метку `c++`?!

Comment: @Harry Извиняюсь .....я наоборот хочу её поставить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вобщем, не вижу смысла...

Но если так уж хочется - то либо явно сместить базовый указатель

```
double *bx_save = new double [101]; 
double *bx = bx_save+50;

for(int i = -50; i<= 50; ++i) cout << bx[i] << endl;

delete[] bx_save;
```

Либо можно вообще свой класс написать, который все это будет делать автоматически.